# How to group by and sum when all elements of one list are in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame df1. "transactions" column has an array of int.

```
id     transactions
1      [1,2,3]
2      [2,3]
```

data frame df2. "items" column has an array of int.

```
items  cost
[1,2]  2.0
[2]    1.0
[2,4]  4.0
```

I need to check whether all elements of items are in each transaction if so sum up the costs.

Expected Result

```
id    transaction score
 1      [1,2,3]     3.0
 2      [2,3]       1.0
```

I did the following

```
#cross join
-----------
def cartesian_product_simplified(left, right):
   la, lb = len(left), len(right)
   ia2, ib2 = np.broadcast_arrays(*np.ogrid[:la,:lb])

    return pd.DataFrame(
    np.column_stack([left.values[ia2.ravel()], 
     right.values[ib2.ravel()]]))

out=cartesian_product_simplified(df1,df2) 

#column names assigning        
out.columns=['id', 'transactions', 'cost', 'items']

#converting panda series to list
t=out["transactions"].tolist()
item=out["items"].tolist()


#check list present in another list
-------------------------------------
def check(trans,itm):
out_list=list() 
for row in trans:
   ret =np.all(np.in1d(itm, row))
   out_list.append(ret)
return out_list

if true: group and sum
-----------------------
a=check(t,item)
for i in a:
  if(i):
   print(out.groupby(['id','transactions']))['cost'].sum()      
  else:
   print("no")
```

Throws TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable.

I am new to python and don't know how to put all these together. How to group by and sum the cost when all items of one list in another list?

Comment: there seems to be problematic indentation with your `check` function?

Comment: i did not get any identation error. What's that?

Comment: Which df is bigger?

Comment: Can df2 gave 1,2,3? I think so.

Comment: dataframe df2 is bigger

Comment: looks like permutations needed from df1, partition results and process in parallel against df2 which has first item as partitioning, likewise df1, but it is not exact

Answer (score 3):

The simplies way is just to check all items for all transactions:

```
# df1 and df2 are initialized

def sum_score(transaction):
    score = 0
    for _, row in df2.iterrows():
        if all(item in transaction for item in row["items"]):
            score += row["cost"]
    return score

df1["score"] = df1["transactions"].map(sum_score)
```

It will be extremely slow on big scale. If this is a problem, we need to iterate not over every item, but preselect only possible. If you have enough memory, it can be done like that. For each item we remember all the row numbers in `df2`, where it appeared. So for each transaction we get the items, get all the possible lines and check only them.

```
import collections

# df1 and df2 are initialized

def get_sum_score_precalculated_func(items_cost_df):

    # create a dict of possible indexes to search for an item
    items_search_dict = collections.default_dict(set)
    for i, (_, row) in enumerate(items_cost_df.iterrow()):
        for item in row["items"]:
            items_search_dict[item].add(i)

    def sum_score(transaction):
        possible_indexes = set()
        for i in transaction:
            possible_indexes += items_search_dict[i]

        score = 0
        for i in possible_indexes:
            row = items_cost_df.iloc[i]
            if all(item in transaction for item in row["items"]):
                score += row["cost"]
        return score

    return sum_score

df1["score"] = df1["transactions"].map(get_sum_score_precalculated_func(df2))
```

Here I use 
`set` which is an unordered storage of unique values (it helps to join possible line numbers and avoid double count). 
`collections.defaultdict` which is a usual `dict`, but if you are trying to access uninitialized values it fill it with the given data (blank `set` in my case). It help to avoid `if x not in my_dict: my_dict[x] = set()`. I also use so called "closure", which means `sum_score` function will have access to `items_cost_df` and `items_search_dict` which were accessible at the level the `sum_score` function was declared even after it was returned and `get_sum_score_precalculated_func`

That should be much faster in case the items are quite unique and can be found only in a few lines of `df2`.

If you have quite a few unique items and so many identical transactions, you'd better calculate score for each unique transaction first. And then just join the result.

```
transactions_score = []
for transaction in df1["transactions"].unique():
    score = sum_score(transaction)
    transaction_score.append([transaction, score])
transaction_score = pd.DataFrame(
    transaction_score,
    columns=["transactions", "score"])
df1 = df1.merge(transaction_score, on="transactions", how="left")
```

Here I use `sum_score` from first example of code

P.S. With the python error message there should be a line number which helps a lot to understand the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But i will have millions and millions of row of items.  I need a faster solution.

Comment: Just added an update, which makes it much faster in case there are lot of unique items and they aren't used heavily among many lines of `df2`

Comment: Thanks. But the problem is in real time i am working with sensor data. I don't have a lot of unique items. Sensor values deviate only over a period of time. until then all the rows will have similar sensor readings.

Comment: If you have only a few possible items, is that correct, that there might be a lot of identical transactions?

Comment: yeah could be lot of  identical rows. Example sensor data is here. http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00362/

Comment: Just updated the answer with a code highly efficient when there are lots of identical transactions.

Answer (score 1):

```
# convert df_1 to dictionary for iteration
df_1_dict = dict(zip(df_1["id"], df_1["transactions"]))
# convert df_2 to list for iteration as there is no unique column
df_2_list = df_2.values.tolist()

# iterate through each combination to find a valid one
new_data = []
for rows in df_2_list:
    items = rows[0]
    costs = rows[1]
    for key, value in df_1_dict.items():
        # find common items in both
        common = set(value).intersection(set(items))
        # execute of common item exist in second dataframe 
        if len(common) == len(items):
            new_row = {"id": key, "transactions": value, "costs": costs}
            new_data.append(new_row)

merged_df = pd.DataFrame(new_data)
merged_df = merged_df[["id", "transactions", "costs"]]

# group the data by id to get total cost for each id
merged_df = (
    merged_df
    .groupby(["id"])
    .agg({"costs": "sum"})
    .reset_index()
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i am testing its scalability

Comment: Did it scale enough? @priya

Comment: For 8 million rows it takes 1.23 mins.

Comment: Strikes me as ok @priya

Comment: Why a dict is used?

Comment: @thebluephantom I needed iterable to solve that problem. I could use list for both iterables. As first one has a unique ID so instead of using list I convert it to collection.

Comment: OK, got it, indeed.