# Pyspark- How to achieve parallelism for a given algorithm that is otherwise less performant?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have two dataframes

```
df_1 = spark.createDataFrame(
[(1, [(1), (4), (2) ,(3)])],
("id", "transactions")
)

df_2 = spark.createDataFrame(
[([ (1),(2),(3)], 2.0) ],
("items", "cost")
)
```

i have an UDF to check whether all elements of an array present in another array. 
I use spark 2.2

```
 @udf("boolean")
 def contains_all(x, y):
    if x is not None and y is not None:
       return set(y).issubset(set(x))


costs=(df_1
.crossJoin(df_2.groupBy("id", "transactions")
.agg(sum_(when(
 contains_all("transactions", "items"), col("cost")
 )).alias("score")))
```

Since one of the dataframes (df_2) is extremly large, the above code is very slow (Already a day and still running).

How can i perform the above operations to run parallely? 
Should i convert the dataframes to rdd? Is there any way to speed up?
Any example of this type would be great.

Comment: Please provide a full minimal example so we can try to optimize it.

Comment: Hard problem for sure.

Comment: Note nobody has commented. Have you advanced your approach yet?

Comment: @thebluephantom i have few optimised solutions for this problem in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55703303/how-to-group-by-and-sum-when-all-elements-of-one-list-are-in-another-list/55703583?noredirect=1#comment98290713_55703583. But difficult for me to convert into Pyspark.

Comment: @thebluephantom It would be great if someone atleast tell how to partition the tasks  and to run parallel in several machines.

Comment: The problem looks easy enough but it is not normal parallel consideration. Do you need to process all found existencies?

Comment: Indeed u do when I look at link. Will look tonight

Comment: Spark works with default parallel settings unless you override, but the algorithm needs to be able to run in parallel. This is a tough one which looks like it could be an  issue.

Comment: @thebluephantom Thanks for the reply.  so you say, it is not difficult to optimise the code.  But difficult to parallelize?  If so how would you optimise?

Comment: I will look at the other code example and assess. I am in hols but will look later tonight. do yoy kniw how parallellize works in Spark?

Comment: Thanks. No i don't. I am new to spark.

Comment: pattern mining as far as I can see or a variation

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192739/discussion-between-priya-and-thebluephantom).

Comment: Too much work to solve for 15 pts.